# display downloading progress bar

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I have used progress bar for displaying downloading data using AsynkTask.But when user press the back key and again going into that activty then progress bar doesn't displaying any progress but actually data is downloading in the background.So how to display current progress in progress bar when user going to that screen again?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a progress bar, use a progress fragment, this is the new design practice. Also I highly recommend using RoboSpice https://github.com/octo-online/robospice, as it will take care of a lot of the hassle associated with AsyncTasks.

For the Progress fragment, I recommend https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment